# Android webview get url return null

Tags: android, url, webview

In my case, i have an app which is a webview application. 4.1 or above to use the getUrl() will return the path. but when i use the android 4.0 it will return null.
I have do a lot of search for this situation. but can not find the answer.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: write more code and whats you try and where error ?

Answer (score 0):

"`public String getUrl ()` gets the URL for the current page. This is not always the same as the URL passed to WebViewClient.onPageStarted because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed." (c) [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl())

So, if your page doesn't load yet then getUrl returns null to you. Try to call it, for exampe, in onPageFinished in your custom WebViewClient.

Comment: i have already use it before then it is work between 4.1 - 4.4. but when i use the 4.0 device which just not working.

Comment: @user2357288 I tested it on HTC Sensation (4.0). All worked fine.

Comment: i still can not fix the issue. but i used another method to handle this. maybe that will be simple and flexible. anywhere, thanks for your advise. =]